# How to Launch Terminal Script with Appliation Icon?

Tags: bash, xubuntu, scripts, tor

I am relatively new to linux, but I wanted to get my Tor browser up and running. I have downloaded and extracted the Tor Browser Bundle. In order to open the browser I need to cd to the file and run a start command for the program. What I am looking to do is make it an icon within my other applications (I am using Xubuntu 14.04 64bit). For example, when I hit the xubuntu icon in the top left of the screen, it comes up with programs, that is where I want to display a Tor Browser Icon. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a desktop launcher for your program.
It must have .desktop extension.Open a text editor first,write necessary lines  and then save it with .desktop extension.

For example tor.desktop

[Desktop Entry]

Version= version of the program(like 0.5,etc)

Name=tor

Comment=tor browser (any comment you wish)

Exec=a path to the start command

Icon=a path to the icon (you have to prepare your icon, it must be .png format,you may take them form web)

Terminal=false

Type=Application

Categories=Utility;Application;Internet

After creating it make sure make it executable.

See the link for detailed info:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles